# trigonometric range of given function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I came up with this sum in my exam its like what is the range where $$\frac{\tan(x)}{\tan(3x)}$$ is never defined . I made all terms in $tan(x)$ and then was going to differentiate but that approach in a competitive exam seems useless . Any good hints, solution !!

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Indeterminate.html

Comment: How can you guys answer such an ill-formulated question ?

Comment: whats wrong in it so that i can edit

Comment: Your comment is conttadictory can you edit it

Comment: No derivative is needed

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\tan x}{\tan 3x} = \frac{\tan x\cdot (1-3\tan^2 x)}{3\tan x-\tan^3 x} = \frac{1-3\tan^2 x}{3-\tan^2 x}$

Now Put $\tan x=t\;,$ We get $$\displaystyle y=f(t) = \frac{1-3t^2}{3-t^2}$$

So $$y(3-t^2) = (1-3t^2)\Rightarrow 3y-t^2y = 1-3t^2$$

So $$(3y-1)=t^2(y-3)\Rightarrow t^2= \frac{3y-1}{y-3}$$

Now Using $$t^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan 3x = \frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}$$
$$\frac{\tan x}{\tan 3x} = \dots = 3 - \frac8{3-\tan^2x}$$

$$\tan^2x\ge0$$
$$3-\tan^2x\le3$$
$$3-\tan^2x<0 ~~~\text{or}~~~0< 3-\tan^2x\le3$$
$$\frac1{3-\tan^2x}\le 0~~~\text{or}~~~\frac1{3-\tan^2x}\ge \frac13$$
$$\frac8{3-\tan^2x}\le 0~~~\text{or}~~~\frac8{3-\tan^2x}\ge \frac83$$
$$-\frac8{3-\tan^2x}\ge 0~~~\text{or}~~~-\frac8{3-\tan^2x}\le -\frac83$$
$$3-\frac8{3-\tan^2x}\ge 3~~~\text{or}~~~3-\frac8{3-\tan^2x}\le \frac13$$
$$\frac{\tan x}{\tan 3x}\ge 3~~~\text{or}~~~\frac{\tan x}{\tan 3x}\le \frac13$$

Hence:

$$R_{\frac{\tan x}{\tan 3x}} = (-\infty,\frac13]\cup(3,+\infty)$$